# Variable become string even though value assigned is 0

Tags: python, string, types, integer

This is a guessing game, the variable ans here become type str at the while loop and cause an error. TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'. Why is ans a str

```
import random 

def guess(x):
    ansnum = random.randint(1,x)
    ans = 0  
    chance = 0
    limit = 4

    while ans!= ansnum and chance < limit : 
        ans = input(f"Guess between 1 and {x}: ")
        chance += 1 
        if ans < ansnum: 
            print("close,too low") 
        else:
            print ("close,too high")
    else:
        print("You Guess IT")
guess(10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first indeed you initialize it with 0, but it overlapped with the `input()` inside the loop thats returns a string, so the initialization doesn't mean anything. To solve it you have to cast the input to integer

```
import random 

def guess(x):
    ansnum = random.randint(1,x)
    ans = 0  
    chance = 0
    limit = 4

    while ans!= ansnum and chance < limit : 
        ans = int(input(f"Guess between 1 and {x}: "))
        chance += 1 
        if ans < ansnum: 
            print("close,too low") 
        else:
            print ("close,too high")
    else:
        print("You Guess IT")
guess(10)
```